# Transformation / Substitution of configuration files in AWS CodePipeline

Tags: aws-codepipeline, variable-substitution

Finally getting into AWS after several years in Azure.

I have a CodePipeline set-up for a dotnet core lambda function.

Traditionally I have set-up build pipelines and then transformed the configuration files for each release stage.  Azure has an in-built task under the release pipelines that substitutes defined variables with the variables in the configuration file you direct it.  It also does transformation in that I can take a appsettings.release.json and save it as appsettings.json.

This is all done post build and right before binaries are deployed.

I am looking for the similar capability in CodePipeline.  Ideally storing my runtime values in either environment variables or the SecretsManager.